# how to load xml file to jsp/html page using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp, jquery

I have an xml file created in E drive `E:\xmlData.xml`.
I need to load this xml file into `jsp/html` file on page load using  JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: As far as I know, JavaScript can only read local files through a file-upload form.

Comment: @JCOC611: Can't we use some jquery ajax to get the file from remote location ie driver

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking JavaScript is client-side technology. It doesn't have access to your local file system and you can't load a file from there. But HTML5 provides the File System API. It allows you to solve your issue. Here's an [example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Rest API based server. which will return the xml when the request is given by an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a method $.get which can capture the data from a URL. So to "read" the xml document, it needs to be accessible through a URL. 
for using jQuery you must download jQuery javascript library from http://jquery.com/
and put it on the current project/solution file.

use this inside the head tag :

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is an example script this will alert xml file content on load...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var localFileUrl = '/Yourdirectory/file.xml';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get(localFileUrl , function(fileContent) {
            alert(fileContent);
        });
    });
</script>
```